# Format Cell in a column based on previous cell in column - Excel 2019

Tags: colors, formatting, cell, excel-2019

I know there are other answered questions like this but they are either outdated or dont explain how to get to the menu to enter things in. I am a novice Excel user and need a little help in getting cells in a column to be formatted based on the value of the cell above, in the same column. For example:

B3 - 10 
B4 - 11 (Higher value than B3 so should turn green)
B5 - 9 (Lower value than B4 so should turn red)
B6 - 10 (Higher value than B5 so should turn green
...and so on.

[[image: View the screenshot here]

Here is an example. I want to monitor that the amount of apples I buy keeps going up(turn green) but if I get less then than I previously had it should format the cell red.

Any assistance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formulas:

`=F2<F1` - Red

`=F2>F1` - Green

`=F2=F1` - Yellow

---

Start with your list:

[image]

Select Cell F2 and go to conditional formatting.
Select "New Rule" and write the formula `=F2<F1`.
Select "Format..." to decide background color.
[image]

Now we do it for the other condition, `=F2>F1`:

[image]

Now we do it for the other condition, `=F2=F1`:

[image]

Then you choose "Format Painter" and mark all cells down (**incl**. `F2`). So in example I select `F2` to `F14`:

[image]

Result should be like this:

[image]

and your conditional formatting rules manager will look like this:

[image]

---

Trick:

If you want to ignore the first **data** row (i.e. row 2) you can change in the conditional formatting manager to apply for range `F3` in and downward

[image]

and result will be:

[image]

Comment: You're a master! Thank you so much for your time and effort in helping me resolve this. Instructions were clear and easy to understand! Thanks so much

Comment: You're welcome and thanks :). Wish you good luck with your project =)!